# Need to extract a csv file to a new file

Tags: python, file, csv, gzip

I am a python newbie here...

I have a gzipped file (C:\sample.gz) that I have downloaded off the internet and I need help with code that will extract the csv file inside to its own file (C:\sample.csv) all I see is code to load it into memory... is there any way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? If you can load it into memory, you can then write the CSV file to disk yourself, no?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html

Comment: try something and post your code with issue instead just asking how..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use python's [gzip library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html).

```
import gzip
with gzip.open('/sample.gz', 'rb') as my_gz:
    file_content = my_gz.read()
    with open('/sample.csv', 'wb') as my_csv:
        my_csv.write(file_content)
```